# ajax post to spring mvc appends "=" sign to request data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

i am trying to post data though ajax post to spring controller. My ajax code is

```
function postData(tag){
console.debug(tag);

var targetUrl = "/add/tag";
$.ajax({
    url : targetUrl,
    type : "POST",
    data : tag,
    dataType : "text",
    success : function(response){
        console.debug(response);
    },
    error : function(){
        console.debug("error : ".concat(response));
    }
});
}
```

and my controller code is

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add/tag", method = POST, consumes = { "application/json" },headers = "content-type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
@ResponseBody
public Integer addTag(HttpServletRequest request,
    @PathVariable("uid") String gatheringUid, @RequestBody String tag) {
    System.out.print(tag);
    return gatheringService.updateGathering(gatheringUid, tags);
}
```

on server side it prints the value of tag appended by "=" sign, while on firebug console value prints as i enterd.

For example when i post data "test", on firebug console it prints "test" and on server side console it prints "test=".

Can any one kindly tell me what is the problem here.

Thanks in advance,
regards.

Comment: you're sending dataType 'text' and consuming application/json.  You probably want to change your java to consumes text/plain or the equivalent.

Comment: Geoff has a point.
You are printing the request and not the tag.

Comment: Your handler method is completely contradictory.

Answer (score 11):

This is a consequence of AJAX sending your POST with a content-type of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Spring uses a `StringHttpMessageConverter` to resolve the argument to bind to a `@RequestBody` annotated `String` parameter. Internally, this checks if the request was a form POST. If it is, it deserializes the whole body as if it was a form submission. In this case, a single word `text`, appears as if it was, for example, a single `<input>` element with no value, ie. `text=`.

If you're curious, this is done in `ServletServerHttpRequest#getBodyFromServletRequestParameters(..)`.

Change your content-type to something more appropriate, maybe `text/plain`. Don't use `dataType`. Use `contentType` or the `headers`.

Comment: Still getting = even after removing dataType, or changing it to text/plain.

Comment: @geneb. Open the network tools on your browser and check what is being sent. If it's still `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content type, you might have missed something.

Comment: Yes you're right. thanks. Had to do `contentType` on the Ajax JS side -- I was changing `dataType`.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, based on Sotirios' answer, the following worked in the Ajax jQuery code.

```
     $.ajax({
            type : "post",
            dataType : 'json', 
            contentType : 'text/plain', // This was added to delete the =
            url : 'myURL',  
            data : id
     })
```